# ExtJs - How to get value from the Store by id?

Tags: extjs, store

How to get value from the Store by *id*?

store in such fields

```
    fields: [
    {name: "id", type: 'int'},
    {name: "name", type: 'String'},...
```

I need to get the *id* - *name* value.

I try so:

```
    var rec = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("MyStore").getById(id);
    alert(rec.data.name);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function `getById` finds the record with the specified id which has nothing to do to with the id you specified in the fields config - Basically you're looking at `record.id` while you should be looking at `record.data.id`.

For 3.3.1 you should use:

```
var index = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("MyStore").findExact('id',id);
var rec = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("MyStore").getAt(index);
```